# Есть ли реализация на c# гост р34.11-2012?

Tags: c#

Где найти реализацию госта 34.11-2012 для подсчета контрольной суммы файла. Есть на хабре. Но при подсчете фалов большого размера считает очень долго.

Comment: Алгоритм блочный? Если да, то размер файла линейно будет влиять на время, удивляться нечему.

Comment: @Monk вообще-то, любой алгоритм будет иметь время не меньше чем линейное, не важно блочный он или нет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Не любой. Например, сумма первого байта, последнего байта, и длины файла. Это, конечно, крайне своеобразный алгоритм для контрольной суммы, но зато со сложностью O(1) :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov я к тому, что иная реализация того же алгоритма не поможет, если файл реально большой.

Comment: Ну тогда почему md5 тот же не ведет себя так. Который в пространсте system.security.cryptography считает на ура. И быстро. Могу выложить класс котоый нашел.

Comment: @ВячеславБобров время работы md5 линейно зависит от размера файла.

Comment: Проверял один и тот же файл. Размер файла 10мб. Мд5 даже не задумывается. А вот гост думает долго.

Comment: Вот [реализация на С](https://github.com/okazymyrov/stribog), наверное легко должно переноситься.

Comment: @Yaant приведенный вами алгоритм не является криптостойким

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я на криптостойкость и не претендовал. :) Если на то пошло, то всякие там CRC32 или даже MD5 тоже не криптостойки. :)

Comment: гост 34.11-2012 хорош только при хэшировании небольших сообщений. а для использования в качестве контроля контрольной суммы файла медленный. проверил опытным путем.)) Вопрос снят.

Comment: Вы пользовались только классом, который выложили на Хабре? Или нашли какой-то еще? Если что-то иное, могли бы поделиться?